# Module 'psycopg2.errors' has no 'UndefinedColumn' member

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I am trying to catch exceptions while adding entries to a PostgreSQL database through SQLalchemy. Whenever I append an entry with a new column (not in the Postgres table), I get the following error: `psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn`, then a little lower down, another error from another exception: `sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn)`.

Now, I'm trying to handle this exception like so:

```
def to_psql(source, table, engine, if_exists): 

   try:
      source.to_sql(table, con=engine, index=False,
                   if_exists=if_exists)
   except psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn as e:
             print(f"Column exception: {e}")
             data = pd.read_sql(f'SELECT * FROM {table}', con=engine)
             new_source = pd.concat([data, source])
             new_source.to_sql(table, con=engine, index=False,
                               if_exists="replace")
```

But I'm getting the error: `Module 'psycopg2.errors' has no 'UndefinedColumn' member`?

Comment: See the docs for more information [SQL errors](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/errors.html) "42703  UndefinedColumn  ProgrammingError"

Comment: @the man: Whats your psycopg2 version ? Using 2.8.2, `except psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn` works as expected.